# Upload an html entry to Google Docs with base64 encoded images

Tags: html, objective-c, image, base64, google-docs-api

Using objective-c Google Docs API, I'm uploading to **Google Docs** html entries (using mime type text/html) 
with images encoded in base64.

The html img tag appears like:

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,myEncodedString' />,
```

where 
myEncodedString is the img data encoded with base64.
 
The upload is successful, except that the **image isn't displayed.**
**The encoding is right** (I've succeeded in decoding the string back to the original 
image). 

The rest of document is well displayed with the right formatting 
(font, size, color etc, set in the html).

Is a Google Docs server problem? or?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to use base64 encoding 'cause the images are local ones.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't specified what language I'm using. I'm using the objective-c Google Docs api to create some docs from an iphone app. When I sign in to my account I can see the new docs, but instead of the image I see a light yellow area.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem :-( ... 7 years later :-(( but in JS. When I upload text/html emails with inline images in base64 format to Google Docs, the images vanish. The only way to get them appear in Google Docs, is to store them and provide a publicly available url.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the comma and the string.

Comment: sorry, the real code is `[body appendFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64,%@",[imageData base64Encoding]];`. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to edit the question.